# Why value of "document.form1.yourname" changed even if I set onsubmit="return false;"

Tags: javascript, html

The html code is as following:

```
<form name="form1" id="formid1" method="get" onsubmit="return false;" >
Please enter your name:
<input type="text" name="yourname">
<input type="submit" value="please submit"> 
</form>
```

When button is clicked, the value of document.form1.yourname will change to the value of user input, although I set: onsubmit="return false;"

So I get confused. Onsubmit() event will be cancled since I set  onsubmit="return false;". Then why the value document.form1.yourname still changed?

So the assignment of document.form1.yourname does not occur in Onsubmit()? When does the assignment happen?  How to prevent this assigment?

Comment: Hi, first of all the code that you have posted here is wrong you are missing a ">" at the end of the first line (form). 
2ndly, unless you have some JavaScript manipulating the fields, the value should not change.

Comment: xeroxoid, The value should change without any javascript manipulating code. This value assignment of document.form1.yourname has nothing to do with javascript, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` properties of form controls in the DOM represent their *current*, *live*, value.

They do not represent (except sometimes by coincidence) the value they held last time the user was on the same page and left it by submitting the form.

You cannot prevent the value of the `value` property from changing other than by preventing input into the input.

If you want to get the default value, then use `getAttribute('value')`.

Comment: Or better `defaultValue` property.

Comment: Thanks, Quentin.  So by "represents their current live value", you mean, when the user has some input in the html text box, the value of document.form1.yourname will immediately change even if button is not clicked at all? I am interested in exploring when/how this asisgment happened. Would you give some reference link?

Comment: _“I am interested in exploring when/how this asisgment happened”_ – the browser handles that, as soon as the content of the input field changes for whatever reason; it has nothing whatsoever to do with the user clicking any additional buttons. After all, you _see_ the content of the input field change as soon as you type characters into it – so why would you expect the value, when queried via script, to do anything but reflect that?

Answer (score 0):

There are different concepts named "value":

- **A form control's [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-value)**

  > Form controls have a **value** and a checkedness. (The latter is only
  >   used by [`input`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) elements.) These are used to describe how the
  >   user interacts with the control.

  This is changed when:

  - User modifies the form control.
  - You change the [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) content attribute.
  - You change the [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value) or [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-textarea-defaultvalue) IDL attributes.
- **The [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value) IDL attribute**

  > The `value` IDL attribute allows scripts to manipulate the [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-value)
  >   of an [`input`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) element. The attribute is in one of the following
  >   modes, which define its behavior:
  >
  > - **value**
  >     On getting, it must return the current [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-value) of the element. On setting, it must set the element's [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-value) to the new value,
  >     set the element's [dirty value flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-value-dirty-flag) to true, invoke the [value
  >     sanitization algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#value-sanitization-algorithm), if the element's [`type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type) attribute's
  >     current state defines one, and then, if the element has a text entry
  >     cursor position, should move the text entry cursor position to the end
  >     of the text field, unselecting any selected text and resetting the
  >     selection direction to none.
  > - **default**
  >     On getting, if the element has a [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) attribute, it must return that attribute's value; otherwise, it must return the empty
  >     string. On setting, it must set the element's [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) attribute
  >     to the new value.
  > - **default/on**
  >     On getting, if the element has a [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) attribute, it must return that attribute's value; otherwise, it must return the string
  >     "`on`". On setting, it must set the element's [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) attribute
  >     to the new value.
  > - **filename**
  >     On getting, it must return the string "`C:\fakepath\`" followed by the name of the first file in the list of [selected files](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-type-file-selected), if
  >     any, or the empty string if the list is empty. On setting, if the new
  >     value is the empty string, it must empty the list of [selected
  >     files](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-type-file-selected); otherwise, it must throw an [`InvalidStateError`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#invalidstateerror)
  >     exception.

  This is changed when:

  - User modifies the form control.
  - You change the [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) content attribute.
  - You change the [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value) or [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-textarea-defaultvalue) IDL attributes.
- **The [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) content attribute**

  > The `value` content attribute gives the default [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-value) of the
  >   [`input`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) element. When the [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) content attribute is added,
  >   set, or removed, if the control's [dirty value flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-value-dirty-flag) is false, the
  >   user agent must set the [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-value) of the element to the value of the
  >   [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) content attribute, if there is one, or the empty string
  >   otherwise, and then run the current [value sanitization algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#value-sanitization-algorithm),
  >   if one is defined.

  This is changed when:

  - You change the [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) content attribute.
  - You change the [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-textarea-defaultvalue) IDL attribute.

You can prevent the user from modifying the value (and thus the `value` IDL attribute too):

- Making it read-only.

  You can do this adding the [`readonly` content attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-readonly), or setting the [`readOnly` IDL attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-readonly) to `true`.

  ```html
  <input readonly="readonly">
  ```

  ```js
  myInput.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  ```

  ```js
  myInput.readOnly = true;
  ```
- Cancelling the [`beforeinput`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-beforeinput) event.

  ```
  myInput.addEventListener('beforeinput', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
  });
  ```

  Note neither Firefox nor Chrome support it yet.

If you want the user to be able to modify the value, but you want to get the default value, you can use

- The [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) content attribute:

  ```js
  myInput.getAttribute('value');
  ```
- The [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-textarea-defaultvalue) IDL attribute:

  ```js
  myInput.defaultValue;
  ```